# How to edit Tree Control Node Text?

Tags: x++, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I am new to Microsoft Dynamics AX 2012 and am trying to edit the tree view control on the form EcoResCategory so that the text displayed for each node is the concatenation of EcoResCategory.Name and EcoResCategoryTranslation.FriendlyName.  I've searched through all of the X++ code within the methods of the form and haven't figured out where I can modify it to do so.

Does anyone have any pointers or leads on how to achieve this?  It can't be as complicated as I am making it out to be.  Documentation seems to limited with X++ as well.

- Note the form did what I am trying to at one point but the customization was deleted.  I'm not sure if our vendor added this in or if it came native.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `initializeHelper` method of the EcoResCategory class, there is an initialization line that reads

```
EcoResCategoryLookupParameters lookupParameters = new EcoResCategoryLookupParameters(false, false, false);
```

The second boolean paremeter is `boolean _showFriendlyNameWithName` (documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ecorescategorylookupparameters.new.aspx)

My guess would be that if you set this to `true` instead of `false` you will get the requested behavior.

Comment: That was what I was looking for.  Worked like a charm.